# Fraction class overflow (C++)

Tags: c++, math, fractions

I've built a normal fraction class for basic operations. Only problem is that since there a huge number of operations ( I'm doing Gaussian Elimination ) there is an overflow either for the numerator or denominator.

I have a 100 equations, so a 100 x 100 matrix. And the final result needs to be accurate to 10^-6. What should I do?

Comment: Pls tell us the language, in question and tags

Comment: Simple options are probably to detect overflow and round to a nearby rational, or to simply use arbitrary precision variables for both numerator or denominator.  The former won't guarantee precision, but the latter will (of course). I don't see what you could do otherwise.

Comment: The numerical analysis approach would be to use floating point arithmetic for elimination, and then possibly iteratively refine your solution if the accuracy proves worse than what you need.  The matrix has a "condition number" that roughly assesses how the numerical errors (rounding) in the right hand side affects the answer's accuracy, and the condition number (or an estimate of it, at any rate) is something a well-written Gauss elimination routine can give you "for free".

Answer (score 2):

As @Chris A already suggested in his comment, I would use arbitrary precision integers for denominator and numerator. An example implementation you could use is [GNU MP Bignum](http://gmplib.org/).

And make sure you simplify ("cancel") the fraction as soon as possible! This keeps denominator and numerator small. Therefore, the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) might be of interest.

Comment: In many cases, going to a bignum approach will (a) make things very slow and (b) won't solve the problem. The problem here is that its dubious that there really are 100 degrees of freedom. Assuming that there are 100 DOF and using a bignum type solution will lead to overfitting if there are only (for example) 20 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting overflow/undeflow because your 100x100 matrix is ill-conditioned. If you aren't using partial pivoting, you should be.

A better alternative is to use something other than Gaussian elimination. Even with partial pivoting, Gaussian elimination is still subject to problems related to ill-conditioned matrices. One alternative is to use construct a pseudoinverse via singular value decomposition. Decompose your matrix A to a UVW* form using SVD. A pseudoinverse of A is UV^{-1}W*, where V^{-1} is a pseudoinverse of the diagonal matrix V. This is easy to calculate: Just find the inverse of each diagonal element, except that you use the seemingly paradoxical 1/(small number) = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using exact rational arithmetic for algorithms that require ~670000 arithmetic operations is doomed to failure. How could you ever have thought otherwise? If you need a result accurate to `10^-6`, then work to an accuracy of (oh, I don't know) `10^-20`, and use pivoting.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Algorithms) (equiv. to the row reduction phase of Gauss elimination without pivoting) of a full NxN matrix A requires ~2N³/3 multiplications and divisions.  Even with partial pivoting this operation count holds.

Floating point arithmetic can entail rounding errors at every step.  "Forward" error analysis of the elimination steps doesn't produce a useful estimate of accuracy, because in the worst case rounding errors can accumulate exponentially.  However J.H. Wilkinson showed ["backward error analysis](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/gauss-jordan2.pdf) can give realistic estimates, e.g. for A positive definite or diagonally dominant matrices, in which the computed solution by Gauss elimination with full pivoting is the exact solution of a "modest" perturbation of the system to be solved (usually the case as well with just partial pivoting).  The size of the residual error can then be estimated from the size of the perturbation and the condition number of the matrix, usually defined as the ratio of the norm of A to that of A's inverse.  If A is singular, this is infinite, and if A is close to singular, then arbitrarily large.  If the condition number is large enough to amplify the perturbation size (normally the machine epsilon of floating point operations) into greater-than-acceptable residual errors, we say the matrix is ill-conditioned.  Otherwise we say A is well-conditioned.

Of course an idea would be to avoid the rounding errors of floating point arithmetic by using instead exact arithmetic, either integer or rational.

But exact integer-preserving arithmetic generally leads to rapid growth of entries and hence overflow, even if the matrix is well-conditioned in the above sense.  [Various strategies](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-103/S0025-5718-1968-0226829-0/S0025-5718-1968-0226829-0.pdf) for minimizing the growth of entries have been proposed, going back to Jordan (whose name is often linked with Gauss in the version of elimination that computes a matrix inverse instead of the solution of a linear system).  W. Kahan gives [a particularly concise account](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/chio.pdf).  An arbitrary precision integer (or rational) implementation would address this difficulty.

However it seems doubtful that such exact methods could compete with floating point arithmetic on dense matrices.  If a direct method like Gauss elimination does not achieve the desired accuracy, as checked by computing the residual (multiplying matrix A times the computed solution and subtracting it from the vector of right-hand sides), then solving again for a correction term with a linear system with the same matrix A but right-hand sides corresponding to the residual.  If the reduction phase of Gauss elimination was actually done as an LU factorization, then only the backsolve phase is needed to solve for iterative corrections.

Where the best accuracy must be squeezed from the available floating point precision, direct methods based on orthogonal matrices are useful (see [Householder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) and [Givens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) transforms).

The bottom line is that solution of linear systems is [an oft-reinvented wheel](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html), and a stronger case for software reuse can scarcely be imagined.  See [the third slide of this presentation](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/nlas-foils.pdf): "How to write numerical linear algebra software -- DON'T!  Whenever possible, rely on existing, mature software libraries for performing numerical linear algebra computations."